# Node JS REST Api restrict origin using CORS partially working. How to block direct Request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, cors

I have a React App talking to a Node JS Api.  I ***only*** want the React App to access the Api. To make this happen I implemented CORS in Node Api:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));
```

Using this approach works.  As a negative test I changed the port number to 4000 and it blocked the Request from the React app. All good!

However, I can take the url to the Node JS Api and put into a browser to make a GET request and it is **NOT** blocked.  I also used Postman to access the Api, it did NOT block the Request.

*Local URL to my API:*

```
http://localhost:9000/resultSummary?studyId=1000
```

How do I block a direct call to the Node JS Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CORS` is used to restrict unwanted `API` calls from one website to another on client side. What you are looking for is authentication. There are few common ones please take a [look](https://nordicapis.com/3-common-methods-api-authentication-explained/).

Answer (score 2):

CORS is something implemented by **browsers** only. It will protect your users by ensuring that your domain will not be accessed from another domain with malicious JavaScript code. If a user decides to make requests on his own, he's still free to request your API as it's public.